# Are Kotlin data classes Value types or Reference type?

Tags: kotlin, value-type, data-class, reference-type

I am from Swift background. Swift has both "value" type & "reference" type support, I am bit curious. Does Kotlin have similar concepts?

By default, any class is a reference type. Whereas, with some digging, I found "data class" in Kotlin behaves as a value type.

I don't have clarity from official documentation.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html

Can some one please help in understanding this concept?

Comment: The difference between data classes and other classes is only a few automatically generated methods like `toString`, `equals` etc. In all other respects data class is just a regular class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data classes in Kotlin don't differ that much from regular classes. They are represented and passed as a reference to an object on the heap.

Kotlin has a limited support for [value/inline classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html):

```kotlin
value class Password(private val s: String)
```

Unfortunately, as for now this is restricted to only a single field per class.

You can find more information in the KEEP, including reasoning on whether to support multiple fields before/after the Project Valhalla: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/notes/value-classes.md